# Pipeline syntax: append to an existing file without using sh ""

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to manipulate a *terraform.tfvars* file during deploy.

Code:

```
         dir("test123/${params.serviceName}/terraform"){
           sh """
           #!/bin/bash -e 
cat <<EOF > ./terraform.tfvars
remote_data = [{
       vpc_state = "${params.targetEnv}/vpc/terraform.state"
       ecs_state = "${params.targetEnv}/ecs/terraform.state"
       bucket    = "${ENV_BUCKET}"
       region    = "${REGION}"
  }]
```

The above lines of code are ugly. Is there an alternative way, such as using `readFile` function in groovy or anything else beside calling `sh` function 
Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to edit the tfvars file? I'm having trouble understanding the goal here.

Comment: I have a tfvars file in the base repo. My goal is to manipulate it during job run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a more elegant way:

```
def remoteData(deploymentDir){
    def data = """
remote_data = [{
       vpc_state = "${TARGET_ENV}/vpc/terraform.state"
       ecs_state = "${TARGET_ENV}/ecs/terraform.state"
       bucket    = "${ENV_BUCKET}"
       region    = "${ENV_BUCKET_REGION}"
  }]
consul_address="${CONSUL_ADDRESS}"
vault_address="${VAULT_ADDRESS}"
service_name="${SERVICE_NAME}"
image_tag="${IMAGE_TAG}"
region="${REGION}"
deploy_role="${ARN}"
dashboard_folder="${SERVICE_NAME}-${TARGET_ENV}"
"""
   writeFile file: "${WORKSPACE}/${deploymentDir}/terraform.tfvars", text: "${data}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be solutions with other terraform features depending on your version, I'm struggling to see why this can't be solved by normal variables. Have you tried loading them via environment variables instead? You would just define the variables in the tfvars, and then they'd be supplied via TF_VARS_ENV_BUCKET [like here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#environment-variables). You could just write the job params directly to envs to make sure they're present.